# Why aren't booleans acting like booleans?

Tags: typescript

Using TypeScript 3.9.5 I've encountered TS error:

> TS2365: Operator '!==' cannot be applied to types 'false' and 'true'

Simplified example (code doesn't doing anything, but represents the flow of the actual function):

```
function _huh() {
  let allStatementsMatched = true
  let invoiceIIDsToApply = []

  if (_.isEmpty(invoiceIIDsToApply) === false) {
    invoiceIIDsToApply.forEach(x => {
      if (x.name === 'test') {
        allStatementsMatched = false
      } 
    })

    //  Why does the below statement result in error: TS2365?
    if (allStatementsMatched === false) {

    }
  } 
}
```

I've found [several](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12794) [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2031) issues discussing this, but they all deal with more complex scenarios and I'm unable to see how they apply to my very simple example.

Why is typescript not treating a [boolean like a boolean](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#boolean)? Where is 'true' and 'false' coming from?

Comment: I'm not sure why typescript is giving dubious control flow analysis here, but one thing to note is that it's bad form to compare a boolean to another boolean directly. Just use `if (!allStatemetsMatched)` instead, which not only reads better but gets rid of this error as well.

Answer (score 2):

That's happened to me before, but only when I (by mistake) do something like this:

```
let x: true;
let y: false;
if (x === false) {
  //...whatever...
}
```

As you can see in the snippet, I am declaring `x` and `y` as variables of types `true` and `false` instead of assigning the values like below:

```
let x = true;
let y = false;
if (x === false) {
  //...whatever...
}
```

Make sure you are not making the same mistake. Sometimes that kind of silly errors are difficult to spot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't apply in my case. Even if I declare ```allStatementsMatched: boolean = true``` I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

[I put your code in sandbox and I got](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-typescript-11c6i?file=/src/index.ts)

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'true' and
>   'false' have no overlap

No big deal, typescript again with its superb flow control analysis tries to outsmart me.

```js
let allStatementsMatched: boolean = true;
```

Apparently that didn't help. Weird as that would make it quiet as far as this variable is concerned in scope.

```js
let allStatementsMatched = true as boolean;
```

Looks like `true`/`false` doesn't respect explicit type declaration and you have to cast them to make it work.

Comment: The weird thing is that it doesn't seem to believe that the `foreach` could ever change the state of `allStatementsMatched`; if I put `allStatementsMatched = false` outside of the foreach, it understands that `allStatementsMatched` can be `false. Seems like a bug to me